# Jest test Vuetify Dropdown

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

I want to test a Vuetify select for its current text.

Checking the entire wrapper eg wrapper.text() doesn't contain the relevant text, and the Vuetify text isn't even rendered inside mount (though the element does exist).

I want to do something like:

```
expect(wrapper.find("[data-test-id=mySelect]").vm).text().toBe("myString")
```

where I can interrogate a property on top of .vm to get the text.

Is this the right approach? How can I get the values of a mounted Vuetify component more easily?